# Storing the output of web-scraping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, web-scraping

I've got a small web-scraping utility in Perl that I am thinking of reimplementing in JavaScript to share with a couple of other people.  Ideally I would like to send them a page with the complete JavaScript program embedded to run standalone on their own machines.  I need to be able to store results from run to run.  I had expected to be able to find an interface to an RDBMS such as SQLite.  I am surprised that there doesn't seem to be anything like this for Firefox.  What am I looking for as far as a relational database storage solution from JavaScript?

Comment: Are you thinking of running this Javascript within a webpage in a browser?

Comment: If your goal is to have a page/site that hosts your code, and allows scraping *other* sites in *other* domains, you're going to run smack into basic browser security restrictions.

Comment: ... but if you're talking about doing this from something like Node.js, there are all sorts of RDBMS connectors.

Comment: you want in-browser sql storage ?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider sticking a RESTful API in front of a database server.  Chose your stack.  If you are not married to a RDBMS consider CouchDB, which has a wonderful RESTful API out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more "inside-the-scope-of-your-question" answer is to use a DB API like Google's Gears API: [Link to Gears](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_database.html)

This provides a local browser storage solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly "outside-the-scope-of-your-question" answer, but it may be better to look at a free scraping utility that already handles XSS and RDBMS storage. Check out WSO2's mashup server.

[Link to Mashup Server Project Page](http://wso2.org/library/mashup-server)

It uses X-family (XPath, XSLT, XML) acquisition and formatting and Javascript for any business logic. You can save the results to a DB or expose them as a web-service. Pretty flexible Java-based solution. Just need a JVM to run.

Best of luck!